# Unable to copy the output of the solution to a directory using MSBuild

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I am trying to build web application and copy the output to build\bin\debug folder in the root. But the folder structure is getting created for every project that is referenced in the web application. I need output of web application and all referenced dll's in the root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDir>build\bin\$(BuildConfig)</BuildDir>
    <BuildConfig>Debug</BuildConfig>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectToBuild Include="testwebapp.sln">
    <Properties>OutputPath=$(BuildDir);Configuration=$(BuildConfig)</Properties>      
   </ProjectToBuild>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">  
   <Message Text="Building solution..."/>
   <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)" Targets="Build">
   </MSBuild>
</Target>
</Project>
```

But it is working if I execute it using command line prompt like

```
msbuild "testwebapp.sln" /t:build /p:OutputPath="custompath"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties evaluate in order so your

```
<BuildDir>build\bin\$(BuildConfig)</BuildDir>
<BuildConfig>Debug</BuildConfig>
```

should be

```
   <BuildConfig>Debug</BuildConfig>
    <BuildDir>build\bin\$(BuildConfig)</BuildDir>
```